# What is another way to say "I needed to explore beyond my comfort zone"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, terminology

I'm writing an essay for medical school applications. Both my parents were physicians, so it is what I was familiar with growing up. Instead of pursuing medicine in college, I decided to pursue something else and try a few different careers after college. Now I'm back on the medicine path and I'm trying to explain why I needed to try other stuff first. I'm hesitant to use the word "comfort zone" because I think it implies that medicine would be the comfortable (i.e., easy) path, when that is not the case. Any other phrases come to mind that explain this sentiment?

Comment: /exploring areas of endeavor outside my personal experience/ But that implies you have already mentioned that both your parents were doctors.

Comment: Think outside the box, color outside the lines, break the cycle, break the rules, lose your security blanket.

Answer (score 2):

I felt I needed to broaden my horizons.

> *broaden/widen somebody's horizons*
>
> to increase the range of things that someone knows about, has
>   experienced, or is able to do
>
> *This trip to the Far East has certainly broadened our family's*
>   *horizons.*

[Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/broaden+horizons)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above:  *stretch myself, learn something new, explore different options, expand myself.*  I don't know which if any of those would be good for your application, though.

Thing is, I'm certain the person reading your application won't believe that's why you did it (to stretch outside your comfort zone).  You tried a different career because you thought you'd like it better than medicine, right?  If I were reading the application, I wouldn't be bothered by that, but I might be bothered by someone trying to tell me what he thinks I want to hear rather.  However, I'm not an admissions specialist at a medical school, so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: I'd say that's good advice!